# Ipa installation loop

Tags: ios, iphone, loops, codenameone, ipa

I have created a minimal demo app from the default tab template and the generated apk works correctly on my Android. 
I can get the generated .ipa to the iPhone 4 IOS 7 via iTune but when I try to run the app it just show a message 'installing' and the app stuck in an infinite “installing” loop.

Comment: Please add some code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally indicates a problem with the provisioning profile.  Make sure that our device is one of the devices registered in the app's provisioning profile.  Also, note that you can't install "app store" builds directly on your device.  Those are meant for uploading to iTunes.  You can only install development builds directly.